# Mapbox + Geojson doesnt work with MarkerCluster

Tags: mapbox, geojson, markerclusterer

Im working with a geojson offline who had a variable called `todos`. The files are loaded with no problem on the map, but when I pass the variable to used as a featurelayer they dont work as clustergroup (with the option of zoom in in and out). Is there anyone who can help me with it?
thanks

var marcadores = L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(todos).addTo(mapa);

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer(marcadores).on('ready', function(e) {
var grupoCluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    grupoCluster.addLayer(layer);
});
mapa.addLayer(grupoCluster);
});
```

Comment: I use these code but doesnt work too any ideas?                                  `var marcadores = L.mapbox.featureLayer.loadURL('geojason/todos.js').on('ready', function(e) {
    var grupoCluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
    e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        grupoCluster.addLayer(layer);
    });
    mapa.addLayer(grupoCluster);
}).addTo(mapa);`

Comment: You'll need to provide a full example, preferable in JSFiddle, for this to be debuggable.